# Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories

Tags: bash, unix, cp

Under unix, I want to copy all files with a certain extension (all excel files) from all subdirectories to another directory. I have the following command:

```
cp --parents `find -name \*.xls*` /target_directory/
```

The problems with this command are:

- It copies the directory structure as well, and I only want the files (so all files should end up in /target_directory/)
- It does not copy files with spaces in the filenames (which are quite a few)

Any solutions for these problems?

Comment: What about `find... exec mv` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move files to directories based on extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334014/move-files-to-directories-based-on-extension)

Comment: this question actually answered the question i came here to ask. thank you!

Answer (score 291, accepted):

`--parents` is copying the directory structure, so you should get rid of that.

The way you've written this, the `find` executes, and the output is put onto the command line such that `cp` can't distinguish between the spaces separating the filenames, and the spaces *within* the filename. It's better to do something like

```
$ find . -name \*.xls -exec cp {} newDir \;
```

in which `cp` is executed for each filename that `find` finds, and passed the filename correctly. [Here's more info](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml) on this technique.

Instead of all the above, you could use [zsh](http://www.zsh.org) and simply type

```
$ cp **/*.xls target_directory
```

`zsh` can expand wildcards to include subdirectories and makes this sort of thing very easy.

Comment: Sorry for my bash illiteracy, but what do you mean by "bin"?

Comment: Yes. 'bin it' means to throw it away. Now amended :-)

Comment: Haha got it! Tnx! 

It doesn't quite work for me yet unfortunately...

The "cp **/*.xls target_directory" for some reason does not copy all the files (it only looks 1 subdirectory deep, and does not copy files in subdirectories of subdirectories).

The "find . -name \*.xls* -exec cp ..." command gives me the message "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: `Bash` 4.0+ and `ksh93` also supports `**`. For bash, use `shopt -s globstar` to enable it. For ksh, it's `set -G` or `set -o globstar`.

Comment: How would you do this in bash 3.2?

Comment: That exec is technically less efficient than passing into xargs, which will do it all in as few  cp calls as possible:  `find . -name '*.xls' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t destdir`

Comment: @Taywee - yes. I didn't want to confuse matters, however, and simply focus on the particular issue. A further efficiency measure is always good

Comment: @BrianAgnew Oh, I'm sure, just good to have extra information in the comments for wayward googlers.

Comment: Using this `zsh cp` variant for serching within a directory: `cp -pPR **en.lproj/*.strings SignLocalization`.

Comment: @BrianAgnew This copies the files indeed, however it does not retain the directory structure if used recursively. Is there a quick way of making it retain the directory tree from the source?

Comment: Thanks!  Wanted to grab all images and this expansion with a regex worked really nicely find -E source -iregex ".*\.(jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|mpeg|mp4|m4v|avi|mov|mts|m2ts|vob)" -exec cp {} destination \;  (mac os)

Comment: note that the destination directory must already exist, otherwise this script will simply copy and rename the file to the directory name you supply.

Answer (score 57):

From all of the above, I came up with this version.
This version also works for me in the mac recovery terminal.

```
find ./ -name '*.xsl' -exec cp -prv '{}' '/path/to/targetDir/' ';'
```

It will look in the current directory and recursively in all of the sub directories for files with the xsl extension. It will copy them all to the target directory.

cp flags are:

- p - preserve attributes of the file
- r - recursive
- v - verbose (shows you whats
  being copied)

Comment: This is the same as what I had to do when SSH'd into Bluehost.

Comment: It does NOT preserver subdirs.

Comment: @b005t3r that is by design, it is not supposed to. That was the whole intent of the OP's question. He wanted all files from subdirectories copied into one directory without subdirs

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to preserve sub-directories?

Comment: @MatthewDean You can use the `--parents` flag to `cp` to accomplish that. Something like `find ./ -name '*.xsl' -exec cp --parents {} targetDir/ ';'`

Comment: What do the braces do? and why the ';'

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. I solved it using:

```
find dir_name '*.mp3' -exec cp -vuni '{}' "../dest_dir" ";"
```

The `'{}'` and `";"` executes the copy on each file.

Answer (score 7):

In 2022 the zsh solution also works in Linux Bash:

```
cp **/*.extension /dest/dir
```

works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't create sub folders.

Answer (score 6):

I also had to do this myself.  I did it via the --parents argument for cp:

```
find SOURCEPATH -name filename*.txt -exec cp --parents {} DESTPATH \;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find [SOURCEPATH] -type f -name '[PATTERN]' | 
    while read P; do cp --parents "$P" [DEST]; done
```

you may remove the --parents but there is a risk of collision if multiple files bear the same name.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Ventura 13.1, on zsh, I saw the following error when there were too many files to copy, saw the following error:

```
zsh: argument list too long: cp
```

Had to use `find` command along with `cp` to get the files copied to my destination:

```
find ./module/*/src -name \*.java -print | while read filelocation; do cp $filelocation mydestinationlocation; done
```