# Move files to directories based on extension

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux. I am trying to write a shell script which will **move files to certain folders based on their extension**, like for example in my downloads folder, I have all files of mixed file types. I have written the following script

```
mv *.mp3 ../Music
mv *.ogg ../Music
mv *.wav ../Music
mv *.mp4 ../Videos
mv *.flv ../Videos
```

How can I make it run automatically when a file is added to this folder? Now I have to manually run the script each time.

One more question, is there any way of combining these 2 statements

```
mv *.mp3 ../../Music
mv *.ogg ../../Music
```

into a single statement? I tried using `||` (C programming 'or' operator) and comma but they don't seem to work.

Comment: create a script and run it every few minutes using cron

Comment: Is cronjob an option or do u want something more real time ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no trigger for when a file is added to a directory. If the file is uploaded via a webpage, you might be able to make the webpage do it.

You can put a script in crontab to do this, on unix machines (or task schedular in windows). Google crontab for a how-to.

As for combining your commands, use the following:

```
mv *.mp3 *.ogg ../../Music
```

You can include as many different "globs" (filenames with wildcards) as you like. The last thing should be the target directory.

Comment: even better, use brace expansion i.e. `*.{mp3,ogg,wav}`

Comment: Note that the `mv` command can overrite files if they already exist in that directory

Answer (score 19):

Two ways:

1. `find . -name '*mp3' -or -name '*ogg' -print | xargs -J% mv % ../../Music`
2. `find . -name '*mp3' -or -name '*ogg' -exec mv {} ../Music \;`

The first  uses a pipe and may run out of argument space; while the second may use too many forks and be slower. But, both will work.

Comment: why exactly do you need `find` when simple globbing would suffice?

Comment: find allows will recurse directories, globbing will not

Comment: OP doesn't seem to require recursing

Comment: I write my answers for future searchers as well as the OP, @doubleDown

Comment: _globbing will not_ not entirely true. `bash v4` has new shell option called `globstar` which does recursive on `**`

Comment: Not everyone uses bash version 4 @JS웃

Comment: Your future searchers might!

Comment: Then again, they might not, @JS웃

Comment: how do force move if you have duplicate images?

Comment: it works perfectly if you need to move all files from all subdirectories (any level) to some another folder. it doesn't solve duplicates problem but in my case it works. imho

Answer (score 6):

I like this method:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 

for filename in *; do
  if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
      base=${filename%.*}
      ext=${filename#$base.}
    mkdir -p "${ext}"
    mv "$filename" "${ext}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: The method just moves files to a directory named after their extension.   Then you can move specific extension directories under eg Music  Videos etc in a clearer way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need to add extra information to your answer after posting it, you can click the [edit] link below your answer to update it rather than posting a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is:

```
mv -v {*.mp3,*.ogg,*.wav} ../Music
mv -v {*.mp4,*.flv} ../Videos
```

PS: option -v shows what is going on (verbose).

Comment: On macOS I needed to omit the curly braces: `mv *.mp3 path/to/dir`

Answer (score 3):

[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) will watch the filesystem and perform run commands upon certain events.

You can combine multiple commands on a single line by using a command separator. The unconditional serialized command separator is `;`.

```
command1 ; command2
```

Comment: @andrewdotn: So then what you're saying is that if no MP3s are moved then no OGGs should be moved either?

Comment: BTW, one doesn't have to wait to till the file is closed. In Unix you can move a file around (as long it's on the same device) without affecting programs who still have it open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for loop** to traverse through folders and subfolders inside the source folder. 
The following code will help you move files in pair from "/source/foler/path/" to "/destination/fodler/path/". This code will move file matching their name and having different extensions.

```
for d in /source/folder/path/*; do
    ls -tr $d |grep txt | rev | cut -f 2 -d '.' | rev | uniq | head -n 4 | xargs -I % bash -c 'mv -v '$d'/%.{txt,csv} /destination/folder/path/'
    sleep 30
done
```