# Copy overlapping files based on extension from multiple directories

Tags: bash, scripting, find, cp

I have files in multiple directories which I want to copy only those whose extensions are found on all of the directories. Here is an example:

```
dir1
    file1.txt  
    file2.bcd
    file3.aa

dir2
    file4.ogg
    file5.txt
    file6.bcd

dir3 
    file7.pgp
    file8.bcd
    file9.aa
```

The copy command or script shall copy only `file2.bcd` and `file6.bcd` and `file8.bcd` to the **Output** directory as they're the once common to all directories. This is just an example and the directories have file extensions which has nothing to do with the file type and I want to copy those common to all directories.

```
Output
   file2.bcd
   file6.bcd 
   file8.bcd
```

Had I known the overlapping file extensions in advance, I could have used `find`, `cp` or `mv` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334014/move-files-to-directories-based-on-extension).

Thank you for your help,

Edit: 
I have solved the problem as follows in case anyone needs it.

```
1. Find and print only file extensions. 
2. Sort and count the extensions. 
3. If count equals folders searched, then copy file to output directory.
```

Of course, this approach assumes each file extension is found once and only once in each folder and which happens to be the case of my files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command to copy files to the output dir using
`find ./ -type f -name '*.<file_ext>' -exec cp -r {} /output/ \;`

replace *file_ext* with file extension.

Comment: Thank you but file_ext is the result of the extensions being in all directory.

Comment: you need to adjust command, like to search file in /data , run it "find /data -type f -name '*.' -exec cp -r {} /output/  \; but if you all dir in / then "find / -type f -name '*.' -exec cp -r {} /output/  \; "

Comment: many thanks for your effort to help; but I have solved my problem.