# script to move files based on extension criteria

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've a certain amount of files always containing same name but different extensions, for example `sample.dat`, `sample.txt`, etc.
I would like to create a script that looks where `sample.dat` is present and than moves all files with name `sample*.*` into another directory.

I know how to identify them with `ls *.dat | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`, however I would like to concatenate with something like `|| mv` (the result of the first part) `*.* /otherdirectory/`

Comment: [Move files to directories based on extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17334014/608639), [Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15617016/608639), [Move all files with a certain extension from multiple subdirectories into one directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67503/56041), etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this bash one-liner:

```
for f in `ls | grep YOUR_PATTERN`; do mv ${f} NEW_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/${f}; done
```

It iterates through the result of the operation `ls | grep`, which is the list of your files you wish to move, and then it moves each file to the new destination.

Answer (score -1):

Something simple like this?

```
dat_roots=$(ls *.dat | sed 's/\.dat$//')
for i in $dat_roots; do
    echo mv ${i}*.* other-directory
done
```

This will break for file names containing spaces, so be careful.

Or if spaces are an issue, this will do the job, but is less readable.

```
ls *.dat | sed 's/\.dat$//' | while read root; do
    mv "${root}"*.* other-directory
done
```

Comment: And the second suggestion will break if the file names contain shell meta characters. If that is a problem, it's time to use Perl or Python :-)

Comment: Thnak you, ind it does what I need for now, a more efficient approach will be developped later. KR

Comment: @ArturFonseca Great! Can I have the accepted answer, please? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but this should do the job:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.dat
do
    mv ${f%.dat}.* other-directory
done
```

Setting the nullglob option ensures that the loob is not executed, if no dat-file exists. If you use this code as part of a larger script, you might want to unset it afterwards (`shopt -u nullglob`).