# Script to move through multiple folders and copy only files with specific ext to another single folder

Tags: python, bash, file-handling, file-manipulation

How to make a script (preferably in python, but I'm open for other ways as well) to parse through multiple subfolders and copy only files with certain extension (like .mp3 & .mp4 etc) to another folder in Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: For Bash: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/cp-copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories) (replace `cp` by `mv`)

Comment: I'd use `find` unless there was a compelling reason to write a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to walk your directory tree.  Then, for each file, use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to get the extension.  Note that `splitext` will return the basename, and extension.

Then use [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to copy to your target directory.

A lightweight example (using `/` as your assumed starting point):

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil    

for root, dir, files in os.walk('/'):
    for ffile in files:
        if os.path.splitext(ffile)[1] in ('.mp3', '.mp4'):
            src = os.path.join(root, ffile)
            shutil.copy(src, [YOUR_TARGET_DIR])
```

Comment: You could just use `ffile.endswith(('.jpg', '.png'))`.