# unix/macos - how to find all files and duplicate in place with a different extension

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, cp

So I want to grab all certain files then duplicate them in the same folder/location but with a different extension. So far I have this from another question [Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories):

```
find . -name \*.js -exec cp {} newDir \;
```

I want to duplicate all those `.js` files into `.ts` e.g. duplicate `functions.js` to `functions.ts` wherever it may be.

more examples:

```
a/functions.js
b/test.js
c/another.js
index.js
```

to

```
a/functions.ts
b/test.ts
c/another.ts
index.ts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name \*.js | while read jsfile; do cp "${jsfile}" "${jsfile%.js}.ts"; done
```

1. `find . -name \*.js` list all `.js` files
2. using `read` command to read each line from the output of `fine` command.
3. `${jsfile%.js}` means to remove the suffix `.js` from variable `jsfile`, for example, `a/functions.js` will become to `a/functions`

Comment: Could you write an explanation about what each part is doing? The answer is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to assign variables using `find` and `xargs` and open up all sort of command-line options,

```
$ find . -name '*.js' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'p="{}"; cp $p newDir/$(basename ${p%.js}.ts)'
```

Use `xargs -I {}` to get the output of `find` as input to `xargs`. Use `bash -c` to execute a command.

Here is a demo:

```
$ mkdir -p a b c d newDir
$ touch a/1.js b/2.js c/three.js d/something.js
$ find . -name '*.js' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'p="{}"; cp $p newDir/$(basename ${p%.js}.ts)'
$ ls newDir/
1.ts        2.ts        something.ts    three.ts
```

EDIT (Question changed after hours of initial post). To keep a duplicate in the same directory use the same `cp` command and remove `newDir` and `basename`:

```
$ find . -name '*.js' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'p="{}"; cp $p ${p%.js}.ts'
```

Comment: To clarify, that command was an example from the other question, I want the output to remain in their respective folders. I have added a more detailed example to my question, thanks.

Comment: see my updated comment. Fairly simple modification to my original answer would get you the result you want.