# macOS - Copy all specific filename found in directories to another directory

Tags: macos

I would like to copy all (in this case) mp4, jpg, png files which are in different directories. I would do this in macOS terminal.

For instance :

```
./dir11/dir2/im.png
./dir11/vi.mp4
./dir12/ima.png
./dir12/main.py
./dir12/dir2/infos.txt
./img.jpg
```

Result : Copy mp4, jpg and png files in `found/`

```
./found/im.png
./found/vi.mp4
./found/ima.png
./found/img.jpg
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using `rsync`**

`$ find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png|mp4)' -exec rsync -avzh {} ./found/ \;`

**using `cp`**

`$ find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png|mp4)' -exec cp {} ./found/ \;`

PS - Not sure which one is more efficient. I usually prefer `rsync` for the copies & moves.

Comment: When I test yours commands (rsync et cp ways), I get the "find: illegal option -- t" error :/

Comment: It's just a `-` not `--`, not sure why it's formatting like this.  `find -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(mp4\|jpg\|png\)" -exec rsync -avzh {} ~/found/ \;`

Comment: With rsync use `-avzh` & cp `-t` . Should work well on most of unix/linux.

Comment: ahh.. seems like they are not compatible with MacOS. Updated my answer, tried in MacOS, works fine. Give it a shot.

Comment: Your command shows me the right files (thanks for that :D)... but there aren't actually copy in the folder `found` :/

Comment: ah.. you wanted to copy it in `./found`, I was copying it in `~/found/`. Updated my answer, try it one last time ;) .

Comment: Euh... I understand that `~/found/` is the path, so I already edited this :/ In fact it's `../test/' so it doesn't fix the error :/

Comment: Oh... sorry.. I checked in the finder if the files were copied but it actually not refreshing (which it's weird). But the files are actually copied... Thanks you so much :D

Comment: One last question do you have a way to make your command not case sensitive ? A code which copy ".PNG" and ".png" files ?

Comment: I don't think we can integrate something out of the box for this solution but you can certainly add more `regex` like `find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png|mp4|JPG|MP4|PNG)'`

Comment: Thanks, It will work. Tank you for helped me that way :D

Comment: Just one last question :| I would like to preserve creation date, like do  `cp -p file /dir`. So I tried to add `-p` in your second command (cp way) but it didn't work... Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to find a list of different file names, and then pipe it via `xargs` to `cp`:

```
find ./looking -type f \( -name "*.mp4" -or -name "*.jpg" \) | xargs cp -t ./found
```

This will copy files from the folder `./looking` to the folder `/found`...

**edit**

Or in your case you probably just want to replace `./looking` with `./`

**updated version for macOS**

Since macOS cp does not support `-t`.

```
find . -type f ( -iname "*.log" -or -iname "*.jpg" ) | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ../test-out
```

Where:

- The `find` part looks for all files (not folders) named *.log or *.jpg, and not case sensative (-iname instead of -name)
- The `sed` part inserts a "\" before any white spaces in a path
- The `xargs` part uses placeholder (`{}`) to put all the arguments into the `cp` command.