# Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories and preserving structure of subdirectories

Tags: bash, unix, cp

How can I copy specific files from all directories and subdirectories to a new directory while preserving the original subdirectorie structure?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories):

```
find . -name \*.xls -exec cp {} newDir \;
```

solves to copy all xls files from all subdirectories in the same directory newDir. That is not what I want.

If an xls file is in: `/s1/s2/` then it sould be copied to `newDir/s1/s2`.

copies all files from all folders and subfolders to a new folder, but the original file structure is lost. Everything is copied to a same new folder on top of each other.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, it *may* be easier to copy everything and then remove non-Excel stuff in the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec sh -c \
'd="newDir/${1%/*}"; mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$1" "$d"' sh {} \;
```

This applies the `d="newDir/${1%/*}"; mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$1" "$d"` shell script to all `xls` files, that is, first create the target directory and copy the file at destination.

If you have a lot of files and performance issues you can try to optimize a bit with:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec sh -c \
'for f in "$@"; do d="newDir/${f%/*}"; mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$f" "$d"; done' sh {} +
```

This second version processes the files by batches and thus spawns less shells.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
# Ensure that newDir exists and is empty. Omit this step if you
# don't want it.
[[ -d newDir ]] && rm -r newDir && mkdir newDir

# Copy the xls files.
rsync -a --include='**/*.xls'  --include='*/' --exclude='*' . newDir
```

The trick here is the combination of *include* and *exclude*. By default, `rsync` copies everything below its source directory (`.` in your case). We change this by excluding *everything*, but also *including* the xls files.

In your example, *newDir* is itself a subdirectory of your working directory and hence part of the directory tree searched for copying. I would rethink this decision.

NOTE: This would not only also copy directories whrere the name ends in `.xls`, bur also recreated the **whole** directory structure of your source tree (even if there are no xls files in it), and populate it only with xls files.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this works? `--exclude='*'` excludes also directories... and so `rsync` does not even traverse them. Testing with `rsync  version 3.2.7` confirms this here. Plus, even if it was working, it would also sync a directory named `sheets.xls`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Good point. Just re-tested it. My original test data had been too simple. I thought that due to the `-a` option, `rsync` would not simply prune an excluded directory tree.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Fixed it, I think. At least it seems to work here. Please check. I don't understand why it would not copy a directory `...xls`.

Comment: This creates all directories, even if they do not contain any `xls` file. Probably not what the OP want. And it **would** copy a directory named `sheets.xls`, even if a directory is not a file.

Comment: Of course it would also call a directory _sheets.xls_. Not sure whether the OP really meant all plain failes named that way, or every directory entry. For clarity, I will put this into my answer.

Comment: Well, they asked _How can I copy specific **files** from all directories..._.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solutions.

Meanwhile I found also:

```
find . -name '*.xls' | cpio -pdm newDir
```